# PIC32MX350F256 Errata , IO open Drain Issue

Tags: microcontroller, pic, i2c, spi, pullup

In one of our Product we used Microchip micro controller “ PIC32MX350F256L”. Attached image is small part of circuit showing uC interfacing with a SPI device. We are using bit banging communication programming for SPI. We also used MOSI,SCLK,CS,MISO and one INT line is as open drain config in uC.

[image]

"***every line has separate 5.6K pull up resistor"***

Slave device generate the Interrupt when its slave data is ready to read,
During testing we found that micro controller not able to detect if any level change on this INT pin.we tried to check with Scope as soon as we touch the probe on INT line , that time only uC detect the INT. ( **So on INT IO we change it from open drain to internal pull up enable, so we have both internal and external pull on line, this time everything is fine**)

We also refer the micro controller errata sheet states that “**The Open Drain selection (ODCx) on I/O port pins is not available when the pin is configured for anything other than a standard port output.  In addition, the Open Drain feature is not available for dedicated or remapable Peripheral Pin Select (PPS) output features”**

Now Hardware is already design, **and we prefer to keep external pull always on line. also we prefer bit banging programming**. Now Current revision also have the same Errata. how can we Workaround this issue.

1. Should we change all Input pin (open Drain) to Internal pull up enable.(with External pull also there)
2. Should we change all Output pin (open Drain) to Internal pull up enable.(with External pull also there)
3. Both 1 and 2.
4. What happen in I2C bit bang programming, since I2C need internal open drain.

Comment: Do you have 1 pull up resistor shared across all 5 lines, or a pull up resistor per line?

Comment: NO , every line has separate 5.6K pull up resistor.

Comment: The term "Open Drain" doesn't have any meaning when applied to an input. "Open Drain" is an *Output* configuration.

Comment: Enabling internal pull with external pull wont be any problem ( PIN config as INPUT) if Current does not exit more that IO pin current limit.